# Do I need to take care of unmanaged In-app purchase product?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

As far as I know for managed IAP, if the user has uninstalled the app or changed his device. He does not need to purchase his IAP again as when he try to purchase again the store will tell him he has purchased already (Both App Store and Google Play Store works like this right?)

However for unmanaged IAP, in game currency for example. if the user bought, let's say, 100 game coins. And if he uninstalled the app or changed his device, he lost his IAP, am I right? I am going to deliver my app so now I have to decided which way I need to handle my IAP. I am afraid some users will drive crazy when they lost their in-game currency and rate my app 1 star.

Comment: Yes you are right. For currency in games usually we use to create consumable in app purchase. So don't bother about it. If you want you can handle inApp details from backend for a user through your app.

Comment: I am not going to setup a server for my game. It is just a simple game. So is it the best solution to use unmanaged product and forget about IAP recovery?

Comment: Yes definitely.. You can also use some back end providers like Parse.com to use backed if you want to focus on recovery.

Answer (score 0):

If your IAP is a "non-consumable" then the user has to be able to recover the IAP.  That can be done by creating a 'restoreCompletedTransactions' function.

If the IAP is a 'consumable' then you do not need to restore this purchase to the user nor do you need to allow the user to get access to this IAP from other devices owned by the same user.  However, if you want to do that, it can easily be done through the user's iCloud account.